# How to create a pivot table on a multiple answer field?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I am keying some data and one question from the data set supports multiple answers. As best I can tell, I have the choice of keying this as a delimited column, e.g.

```
Answer1
------
A
A,B
C
B,D
```

Or, I can key it as multiple columns:

```
Answer1      Answer1
-------      -------
A     
A            B
C
B            D
```

Either way, I need to be able to summarize this data using a pivot table, but I'm not sure how to go about this? Suggestions?

The resulting pivot table should look something like:

```
Answer1     Count
-------     -----
A           2
B           2
C           1
D           1
```

Comment: What do you want to show in your pivot table?

Comment: Edited to add pivot table example

Answer (score 2):

Add calculated columns where `$A2` is the column containing the comma-separated list and `"A"` is whichever answer you want to count in the calculated column.

```
=IFERROR(FIND("A",$A2)^0,0)
```

This assumes that a given answer can only exist once in `A2`. If it finds it, the location is raised to the power of zero, which gives you `1`. If it can't find it, you get an error which results in `IFERROR()` producing `0`.

```
Answer1  1A  1B  1C  1D
A         1   0   0   0
A,B       1   1   0   0
C         0   0   1   0
B,D       0   1   0   1
```

You can now get a sum of each answer either with `SUM()` or by using a PivotTable.

Answer (score 0):

In which case you need to rearrange your data to look like this:

```
Answer 1
  B
  A
  A
  C
  D
  D
```

Then select the data (inc. heading) and put "answer 1" field into **Row** and **Values** fields.

**UPDATE**

As an example, once ethe data is in this format, you can bring it together however you like - such as below:

[image]

Comment: Cannot simply "rearrange" the data. It's part of a larger set. Think of a mail-in survey. Columns could be `FirstName,LastName,...,Answer1,Answer2, etc`. In your case, I'd have duplicate rows for each person depending on the number of answers.

Comment: Excel loves rows, which is why it gives you loads more rows that columns. If you want to use a pivot table in the way you've described you will need to get your data into that format - duplicating rows where people have selected two options. The pivot table will give you flexibility to bring the "duplicated" data back into one place if you want.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add illustration to this point.